# Google .ICS calendar time zone issue

Tags: google-calendar-api

For some reason, we have quite many gmail users that have their Google calendar time-zone not setup properly at all.

When we send them .ICS calendar entry as email attachment, appointment time is displayed wrong in their gmail.

Is there any workaround for generating .ICS  that has some kind of time-zone fix?

Comment: How was event created? using API or in the UI?

Comment: API is being used